# Why isn't the uGUI mask working anymore?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mask, unity3d-gui

I have a Scroll Rect with a Mask on a Canvas set to World Space, it looks fine in Editor but on my Nexus 5 the mask is not being applied. Used to work fine before 5.2 I think but I have made a few changes since last time I tested so I can't guarantee that the Unity update is what broke it.

"Use 32-bit Display Buffer" is checked, "Rendering path" is set to Forward and "Disable Depth and Stencil" is unchecked under Player Settings . The image is a Raw Image.

Any ideas?

Comment: The 5.2 update broke a bunch of stuff in the GUI code. I think I've seen other people complain about this on the forums. Rolling back to 5.1.3 is straightforward if there's nothing you need from 5.2.

Comment: 5.1.4 is now a thing, too.

Comment: have repro'd this problem in 5.1.2, 5.1.4, and 5.2.1p2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-testing with Unity 5.3, the UI system seems to have stabalised a bit and has also had it's masking components replaced with a new clipping framework.

Alternatively try the Soft Alpha UI Mask as part of the UI Extensions project (https://bitbucket.org/ddreaper/unity-ui-extensions) which is a shader based approach with alpha support.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In case this is still relevant to anybody, I've tested a fix proposed [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1128295/android-unity-531f1-the-ui-mask-component-is-pissi.html), which is to **add a Camera GameObject to your scene**.
I'm using Unity 5.3.4f1 to make a UI only mobile game (every component is a UI component since I don't need anything more than that). Upon adding a camera to the top of the Hierarchy tree (just dropped it there at the top), the problematic mask suddenly works fine.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

Rect Mask 2D works instead Mask.